# Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri is not working in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, referrer

`Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` is not working in IE but it's working in Firefox and Chrome.

When posting form data from one website to another website I am sending a querystring with the url.

In page load I used this code:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.tostring();
```

It gives the correct value in Firefox and Chrome. In Internet Explorer a NULL value is returned. How can I get the referrer?

Comment: Could you define *not working*?

Comment: "Please provide a solution" - Use Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`  is based off the HTTP_REFERER header that a browser should send. But, as with all things left up to the client, it's variable.

I IE will strip that header because of Sicurity issues sometimes , in the belief that it aids tracking user behavior. Also, I'm sure there's some Firefox extensions to do the same thing.

Just append the url to the GET string and redirect based off that